# stdin redirect java process running docker build

Tags: java, bash, docker, processbuilder, wlst

I wrote a java program that uses ProcessBuilder to start "docker build". The Dockerfile contains a RUN instruction that kicks of a shell script that triggers a weblogic wlst script. The script seeks user input from stdin. Is it possible to do PrintStream.write() from the java program to pass input to the wlst script?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Do you mean taking user input durring the docker build?

Comment: @AndreasLorenzen, the input is passwords which the underlying jython script seeks from the user. I have the passwords at the time of running the java program. the end result of this is a docker image with weblogic domain in it. In the dockerfile RUN command, i can say RUN (echo -e "xyz\nabc\n" && cat) | wlst.sh py_script. But I want to be able to pass that using java process.getOutputStream()

Comment: I think the issue here would be, that your java program is responsible for initiating the build - as I understand you. And as such, the stdout from the session that you are running the java program in, will not be able to connect to the stdin in the scope that your script is running in - because it is inside the docker build session.